# Getting unknown column error when selecting data for a derived table

Tags: mysql, subquery, derived-table

I need a query to create a table counting the volume of each value in a given field, but due to the data being insufficient in this one table have had to join another table to gain one additional value (NName):

```
Records_table--------------       Name_table---------
Ref    Score     Iteration        Ref      NName
1      High      1                1        Falcon
1      Middle    2                2        Willow
2      Middle    1                3        Lance
2      Middle    2                4        Ranger
2      Low       3
3      Low       1
4      High      1
4      High      2
4      High      3
```

Output required:

```
NName      High  Middle  Low
Falcon     1     1       0
Willow     0     2       1
Lance      0     0       1
Ranger     3     0       0
```

This is  what I have:
(Edited as I noticed I left in a SELECT field ("Ref") I had removed in my version)

```
SELECT 
    tc.nname AS NName, 
    COUNT(High) High,
    COUNT(Middle) Middle,
    COUNT(Low) Low
FROM
    (SELECT 
        NName, 'High' High, NULL Middle, NULL Low
    FROM
        records_table tr
        JOIN name_table tc ON tc.ref = tr.ref
    WHERE
        tr.score = 'High'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
       NName, NULL, 'Middle', NULL
   FROM
       records_table tr
        JOIN name_table tc ON tc.ref = tr.ref
   WHERE
       tr.score = 'Middle'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
       NName, NULL, NULL, 'Low'
   FROM
       records_table tr
        JOIN name_table tc ON tc.ref = tr.ref
   WHERE
       tr.score = 'Low' ) T 
GROUP BY NName;
```

This is failing with "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'NName' in 'field list' "

What have I done wrong, and what do I need to make this work?

Comment: Could you execute the inner `SELECT` (i.e. the one with unions) and see what are the column names you are seeing in the output?

Comment: I think I would do this differently using conditional aggregation.

Comment: @Darshan Mehta, I executed just the first one, because I no longer had the select statement at the start, I had to substitute the "NName" for the field designation "tc.Nname", this worked. However, when I then run the whole again, it still fails:

Comment: SELECT 
    tc.nname AS NName, 
    COUNT(High) High,
    COUNT(Middle) Middle,
    COUNT(Low) Low
FROM
    (SELECT 
        tc.nname, 'High' High, NULL Middle, NULL Low
    FROM
        records_table tr
        JOIN name_table tc ON tc.ref = tr.ref
    WHERE
        tr.score = 'High'
 UNION ALL.......  
WHERE
       tr.score = 'Low' ) T 
GROUP BY tc.nname;

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'cases.project' in 'field list'

Comment: @P Salmon, you are a star, worked a treat, will post full solution below, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst not strictly what the question is asking (and it is a closed question to which @scaisEdge has given the correct answer) I don't think union is the best way to go here. Consider conditional aggregation

```
select n.ref,n.nname,
          sum(case when score = 'high' then 1 else 0 end) High,
          sum(case when score = 'middle' then 1 else 0 end) middle,
          sum(case when score = 'low' then 1 else 0 end) low
from n 
join r on r.ref = n.ref
group by n.ref,n.nname;

+------+--------+------+--------+------+
| ref  | nname  | High | middle | low  |
+------+--------+------+--------+------+
|    1 | Falcon |    1 |      1 |    0 |
|    2 | Willow |    0 |      2 |    1 |
|    3 | Lance  |    0 |      0 |    1 |
|    4 | Ranger |    3 |      0 |    0 |
+------+--------+------+--------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you - and prompted by your question above I came to the same conclusion (using COUNT rather than SUM, but essentially the same thing) - thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your table alias  is  T  not tc then you should use  T.nname  in main select

```
    SELECT 
            T.`NNAME` AS NName, 
            COUNT(High) High,
            COUNT(Middle) Middle,
            COUNT(Low) Low
    FROM  ( 
        SELECT 
                Ref,`NNAME`, 'High' High, NULL Middle, NULL Low
        FROM  records_table tr
        JOIN name_table tc ON tc.ref = tr.ref
        WHERE tr.score = 'High'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 
               Ref,`NNAME`, NULL, 'Middle', NULL
        FROM records_table tr
        JOIN name_table tc ON tc.ref = tr.ref
        WHERE tr.score = 'Middle'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
               Ref,`NNAME`, NULL, NULL, 'Low'
        FROM records_table tr
        JOIN name_table tc ON tc.ref = tr.ref
        WHERE tr.score = 'Low' 
    ) T 
    GROUP BY T.`NNAME`;
```

Comment: could be you have some garbage char in your query  try retype the NNAME related  code  .. removing all the char between the commas or wrapping the colname with bactiks   ..